# how remove specific text from <div> element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

remove % and keep testing using jQuery

```
<div id="top_content">testing %</div> == 0$
```

I've tried to use this code but it didn't work

```
$('.top_content:contains("%: ")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("%: ").join(""));
});
```

top content is an element inside wordpress plugin

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two reasons your original code didn't work is, first: because you're selecting an element incorrectly; the element has an `id` attribute but you're using class-based selector (`.top_content`); and also because you're trying to split the string of text on a character-sequence – `"%: "` – that isn't present in that string.

While this approach can certainly work:

```js
$('#top_content:contains("%")').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().split(" %").join(""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top_content">testing %</div>
```

It's generally better to use the `replace()` method to modify text, as it replaces the string in one place, instead of having to remember to remove (with `split()`) and then `join()` them together with the desired character.

Below is an approach that uses `String.prototype.replace()` along with jQuery:

```js
// selecting the element(s), and using the
// anonymous function of the text() method
// to update the text; passing in a reference
// the index of the current element in the
// jQuery collection, and a reference to the
// the current text of that element:
$('#top_content').text(function(i,old){
  // here we return the modified string, which
  // simply takes the existing string and
  // replaces the '%' character with an empty
  // string, and then removes any leading/
  // trailing white-space with
  // String.prototype.trim():
  return old.replace('%', '').trim();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top_content">testing %</div>
```

Or, without jQuery:

```js
// we need to reference the textContent of this element
// twice, once to set and once to get; therefore we
// cache a reference to the element (in order to avoid
// querying the DOM multiple times):
let topContent = document.querySelector('#top_content');

// here we set the textContent of the element to the
// value returned by using String.prototype.replace()
// to remove the '%' character and replace it with an
// empty string; and removing leading/trailing white-space
// from the string as above:
topContent.textContent = topContent.textContent.replace('%', '').trim();
```

```html
<div id="top_content">testing %</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 2):

1. Use selector `$('#top_content').(...);` for select element by id
2. Use `$(...).replace(...);` method for rename or delete text

Like this:

```js
var new_content = $('#top_content').html().replace(new RegExp(' %','g'), ''); 
$('#top_content').html(new_content);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="top_content">testing %</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used the wrong selector for id remove '.' and put '#' for selecting the id. And since id selector just returns the element, no whole array of element, hence you cannot use loop function (.each).

Otherwise everything you have done is in the right way.

```
$("#top_content").html().split("%").join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to selector `$('#top_content')`. **top_content** is a id name
2. Target the actual content in `contains()` and `split()` function

```
$('#top_content:contains("%")').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().split("%").join(""));
});
```